# Should I use async/await or promise in react-redux env?

Tags: asynchronous, redux, promise, async-await, react-redux

I'm working on a project with Express as backend and React as front. I'm using react-redux with redux-thunk in React app and I was wondering what's the difference (in terms of exec time, etc..) between using async/await function or promise. I know there's some threads about it but I didn't find a good answer why I should use one rather than other. From my pov async/await maybe is more readable but is the only reason to choose this approach? Is there any substantial difference? Here both examples:

ASYNC/AWAIT EXAMPLE:

```
export const fetchAllUsers = () => {
 return async dispatch => {
   try {
    fetchTokenFunc();
    dispatch({type: FETCH_START});
    const response = await axios.get('/users/list');
    if (response.data.result) {
      dispatch({type: FETCH_SUCCESS});
      dispatch({type: FETCH_ALL_USERS, payload: response.data.result});
    }  else {
        dispatch({type: FETCH_ERROR, payload: response.data.error});
     }
 } catch (error) {
   dispatch({type: FETCH_ERROR, payload: error.message});
 }
  return 'done';
  };
};
```

PROMISE EXAMPLE:

```
export const fetchAllUsers = () => {
 return (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({type: FETCH_START});
   axiosTokenHeader();
   axios.get('/users/list').then(({data}) => {
   if (data.result) {
    dispatch({type: FETCH_SUCCESS});
    dispatch({type: FETCH_ALL_USERS, payload: data.result});
   } else {
     dispatch({type: FETCH_ERROR, payload: data.error});
   }
    }).catch((error) => {
      dispatch({type: FETCH_ERROR, payload: error.message});
  });
 };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between your two examples is the asynchronous syntax you chose to express `dispatch` code. `dispatch` does not care so much whether it is called within a promise chain or within an async/await block, so you can even use callbacks if you really wanted. **Readability** is a fine reason to choose a particular syntax. You are good to use `async` and `await` for that reason.